# How can I completely uninstall eclipse on Ubuntu14.04

Tags: eclipse

I install eclipse on Ubuntu14.04 for hadoop program, and there're always some troubles with the hadoop plugin. So I install and uninstall eclipse for two times. But I'm not sure whether it was completely removed.

The last time I install eclipse from the Ubuntu software center. I click the uninstall button in the software center and then delete the folder /usr/lib/eclipse(where eclipse installed). But I also find 'eclipse.ini' in /etc. Can I delete the file?

In order to completely remove eclipse, what can I do further?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programmers to help each other with programming questions. Your question about removal of software is probably more suited to the sister site askubuntu. http://askubuntu.com

Comment: Can you accept the answer if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can delete the `/etc/eclipse.ini` file without causing any issues in your system.

Additionally, Eclipse stores personal files (workspace configuration, plugin info etc.) under `.eclipse` folder in your home directory which may not be removed when you are performing the uninstall.

Assuming you are the only user using eclipse on that machine you may issue the following command to completely remove all personal config files.

`rm -rf ~/.eclipse`

Comment: Thank you a lot! I have successfully reinstalled eclipse and correctly set the hadoop environment.